# Rawlbolt anchor bolt too much torque required?

Tags: bolts, anchor

I’m using [Rawlbolt](https://www.rawlplug.co.uk/product/r-rbl-rawlbolt-lose-bolt-for-use-in-cracked-and-non-cracked-concrete/) anchor bolts to secure a bracket to clay brick. Drilled holes 14mm diameter, 50mm deep, removed dust & inserted shield. Hammered shield flush then inserted bolt, tightened to 15NM, removed bolt and attached bracket. Now when I try to tighten down the bracket it’s getting really stiff, way more than 15NM. Is this ok? Should I just force it or is something wrong and how would I fix that?

After removing a bolt I can see that they are being bent as they go in.

Comment: What is being bent?  The bolt or threads or the anchor?  Bad threads will always be tighter to turn.  Repair the threads or replace the bolt and/or anchor

Comment: The bolts are being bent. I’ve done 3 and they’re all the same. Don’t think the threads are bad.

Comment: Nothing on that page specifies a 14mm hole, 50mm deep or even any anchor that short. Shortest anchor for a 13mm hole is 90mm. Simplest guess would be your holes are short.  Which bolt is it?

Comment: Thanks, I think I’ve worked out what’s going on now. They said min hole depth of 50mm but that’s only enough for the shield to go in flush. If you want the bolt to go in more than the minimum then you need the full 80mm (for mine). My bolts must have been bottoming out in the hole not just getting stuck expanding the anchor as I thought. I’m going to work around it for the ones I’ve done by packing the bolt with washers or nuts. In the future I’ll drill deeper